# If the derivative of a function is positive (or negative) at all points except at $x=a$, where it is zero, then monotoncity of function at $x=a$.

Tags: calculus, continuity

If the function is indeed monotonic,  what then is the intuitive meaning of $0$ rate of change of $f(x)$ wrt $x$ at $x=a$?

Answer (score 0):

The value of $f'(a)$ is a good predictor of the monoticity behavior of $f$ at $x=a$. If $f'(a) > 0$, then $f$ is increasing, if $f'(a) < 0$ then $f$ is decreasing. The only 'problem case' is $f'(a) = 0$, where that information is not enough to determine the monocity of $f$ at $x=a$. It could be increasing, decreasing, both (if $f$ is a constant) or neither ($x=a$ is a local extremum of $f$).

In that 'problem case', one needs to consult the higher order derivatives to find out how the function behaves locally. If you know about the Tayler series, you can see that the first non-zero derivative determines the behavior. With your description, it seems that the second derivative is also 0 and maybe the third is positive, showing an increasing function.

Comment: I know Taylor expansion series (though I doubt that's what you meant),  and also of nth order derivative test. But I do not have the slightest idea why is that true. I am taking Calculus and am in high school (preparing for JEE-Advanced).

Comment: No, that is exactly the Taylor series I mean. It shows, that near the point $a$, the way the functiom behaves is dictated by the values of the derivatives. That's because, if $x$ is 'near' $a$ (in other words, if $|(x-a)|$ is small), the term $f'(a)(x-a)$ will dominate the next term $\frac{f''(a)}2(x-a)^2$ and all the following. That's because the derivatives and other factors are constant, but the term $(x-a)^2$ will be much smaller than $(x-a)$  if $x$ tends to $a$.  The only case where that is irrelevant is if $f'(a)=0$, because 0 times anything stays zero.